# Angular 2 HttpBackend not compatible with Http

Tags: angular, typescript, karma-jasmine

Hi I have a provider that is using:

construct(http: Http, myService: MyService, events:Events)

In my unit test I am calling

provider = new myProvider(HttpBackend, MyService, Events)

I am getting the following:

```
  TS2345: Argument of type 'typeof HttpBackend' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Http'.
```

Property '_backend' is missing in type 'typeof HttpBackend'.

Answer (score 0):

you have to use `HttpClient` from `@angular/common/http`, instead of `Http` and forget not to include `HttpClientModule` in `app.module.ts`

`import {HttpClientModule, HttpClient} from '@angular/common/http';`

Comment: In the test file or the actual provider?

Comment: add to all the places